# What happens to an activity when another one start?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm working with a push API and, since it registers and gets started as an activity, I would like to know what happens to it

Comment: Please read Android documentation on Activity lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Please read the android docs about activity ..[here is the link to it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During normal app use, the foreground activity is sometimes obstructed by other visual components that cause the activity to pause. For example, when a semi-transparent activity opens (such as one in the style of a dialog), the previous activity pauses. As long as the activity is still partially visible but currently not the activity in focus, it remains paused.

You can read developer site which gives more idea.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html
also refer this
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html